# object smaller than memory limit cannot be allocated

Tags: r, memory

I am running R version 3.3.2 x64 through R studio on 64-bit Windows 10 with 16 gb RAM.

My `memory.limit()` is `[1] 16274` mb and I am using `dummy.code()` to create dummies for a data frame with 445,622 rows and 2,699 unique values that I am generating dummies from (so expecting a 445,622 x 2,699 matrix).

Just before calling `dummy.code()`, my `memory.size()` is `[1] 160.97` mb. However, I am getting the typical memory error:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 9.0 Gb
```

My obvious question is why that is the case since `16274` - `160.97` > `9.0 Gb`. I am suspecting that *"there may not be a large enough contiguous block of address space available into which to map it"* but this explanation is given [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html) for 32-bit builds.

Also, I found out that when initialising a zero matrix with these dimensions,

```
m <- matrix(0, 445622, 2699)
```

it is created without problems so this does not seem to be the reason.

```
> memory.size()
[1] 9204.29
```

But this makes me wonder whether there might be a way of using a pre-allocated matrix to put the dummies and then use them in my `lm` model perhaps?

Any mistakes or misconceptions identified in my logic, please point out..

Comment: Read the opening of the linked answer carefully. The solution to this problem is generally just to rethink your approach or to acquire computing resources with more RAM.